Duplicate Contact Record Not Getting Save
I have set the duplicate rule for the contact object. In that, the Action is Allow to create a contact record even though the Duplicate record is not getting Save. I also deactivated the standard contact duplicate rule. What would be the reason for duplicate contact not getting saved?
